# gdb не подсвечивает синтаксис при использовании в powershell и cmd

Tags: windows, powershell, gdb

Ставил сначала на linux, там в xfce терминале в gdb при дизассемблировании и выводе кода командой list синтаксис подсвечивался, смотрелось приятно. А когда поставил на Windows 10, то от командной строки и шелла никакой подсветки не получил. Может есть какие-то модули для подсветки синтаксиса в любом тексте внутри командной оболочки?

Answer (score 0):

Решение: ставить на wsl, из powershell запускать командой wsl, тогда будет подсветка